# Best(mostly cheapest) way to buy international shares(mostly US) from Australia

Tags: investing, trading, international, shares, online-trading

I would like to buy international shares from Australia. But we have hefty fees charged by the banks (CommSec), ie buy fee, sell fee, inactivity fee, etc.
I'm sure someone has eaten a dog on this subject and can suggest a good way to achieve acquisition of capital without too much fees.

My strategy is to buy and hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cost is your main priority then you will probably want to avoid the brokerage services of banks in any country. Instead, look for an online discount broker. Several large international brokerage firms provide accounts to clients in Australia - [Interactive Brokers](https://www.interactivebrokers.com.au/) or [Fidelity](http://www.fidelity.com.au/), for example.

Before considering opening a brokerage account with any firm, be sure to check that it is registered with the [Australian Securities and Investments Commission](http://asic.gov.au/) (ASIC), as this regulatory oversight is the best guarantee that you can get for the security of your funds. You might also want to check the firm's standing with regulatory agencies in the other jurisdictions in which the firm operates (you can find a list of [broker regulatory agencies](http://bestbrokerdeals.com/broker-regulatory-agencies/) that I have published here), as these will tend to give a stronger overall picture of the firms ethics and track record in terms of compliance.

Finally, as a buy and hold investor, remember that execution fees should be of less concern to you than they are to almost any other type of market participant. It will probably be worth making the effort to avoid any inactivity fees though, as there are now many good brokers who do not apply charges to dormant accounts.